# Join Statements in Access SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access, join, ms-access-2010, left-join

I'm new with SQL and how it works with Access, and I had a problem with a query only returning items from a specific set.

So according to the definitions I read a LEFT JOIN statement is supposed to return all records from the Left table then only specific records from the Right table.  For some reason it will not return all records from my left table.  Please see code below.  It still somehow wants to only return records that have some kind of relationship.  Any Ideas?  I want all records from my left table ( tbl_historicOrg) to be returned then only specific records from the Right table.

```
SELECT tbl_historicOrg.NAME, tbl_historicOrg.Racf, tbl_historicOrg.STATUS, tbl_historicOrg.PCF, tbl_historicOrg.[Date Finalized], tbl_historicOrg.[Hist Month], import_data.SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM, import_data.HOURS
FROM tbl_historicOrg LEFT JOIN import_data ON tbl_historicOrg.Racf = import_data.RACF
WHERE (((import_data.SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM)="System Problems"));
```

Any suggestions or corrections would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The query as stated will return all records from tbl_historicOrg that fit the WHERE Condition. and match the rows up with a corresponding row from import_data where RACF matches.  Post some data and the results you are getting and what you expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like below; get the filtered data and do a `JOIN` with that result set

```
SELECT tbl_historicOrg.NAME, 
tbl_historicOrg.Racf, 
tbl_historicOrg.STATUS, 
tbl_historicOrg.PCF, 
tbl_historicOrg.[Date Finalized], 
tbl_historicOrg.[Hist Month],
tab.SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM, 
tab.HOURS 
FROM tbl_historicOrg 
LEFT JOIN (
select SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM, 
       HOURS,
       RACF
from import_data where SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM = "System Problems" ) as tab
ON tbl_historicOrg.Racf = tab.RACF;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your solution. It worked really well (except the last filtering statement, which caused errors). It does filter out/not include any entries that don't have a number in the hours column. Do you know why that may be?

Comment: Basically, we need all of the historicOrg records to show up (with the above columns), with a column for their system problems, if applicable.

Comment: @jpford, Mind trying again with the edited query. See edited answer.

Comment: Your solution works great. I have an issue with the source data that is causing the problem that I am fixing now. Thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like below, Dont use 'WHERE' clause for second table, its filtering the data for 'import_data.SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM = "System Problems"'

```
SELECT tbl_historicOrg.NAME, tbl_historicOrg.Racf, tbl_historicOrg.STATUS, 
tbl_historicOrg.PCF, tbl_historicOrg.[Date Finalized], tbl_historicOrg.[Hist Month], 
import_data.SCHDLE_EXCPT_NM, import_data.HOURS
FROM tbl_historicOrg LEFT JOIN import_data ON tbl_historicOrg.Racf = import_data.RACF
```